# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape (0,)

Tags: python

Hi guys can you kindly help with the following error

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape (0,)
>
> `<Figure size 1000x800 with 2 Axes>`

Hi guys can you kindly help with the following error

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape
> (0,)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without the source code, it's hard to tell precisely what is the error but this is a typical error from a Python code where you are trying to do an operation on Numpy arrays that are not the same dimensions.

In the error message, the shape `(2,)` refers to an array with 2 elements along one dimension, and the shape `(0,)` refers to an array with 0 elements along that dimension. That is mathematically not possible and that's why you are getting this error message.